# AWS Lambda to copy files within folders in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I would like to know on how can we use aws lambda (python) to copy and move a file from a folder in a S3 bucket to a different folder within the same bucket?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html the example resizes and reuploads the images. You can ignore the resizing part.

Comment: hjpotter92, thanks for the reply, I am using python version of lambda.

Comment: S3 is not a file system, it is just object storage. So there is not file system related tools available. You need to write your own script/AWS CLI/GUI http://s3browser.com/   to do the works.

Answer (score 5):

There is no **move** or **rename** command in Amazon S3.

Instead, you can **copy** the object to a new name/location and then delete the original object.

Use [the boto3 `copy_object()` command](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object):

> Creates a copy of an object that is already stored in Amazon S3.

The destination can be the same bucket or a different bucket (even a bucket in a different region!).

Please note that *folders* do not actually exist in Amazon S3. Rather, the name of the object ('Key') contains the full path and filename. Therefore, moving an object to a different folder involves saving it with a different Key (which includes the path).

Comment: Using boto _copy()_ worked for me as I needed to specify the exact location where it was to be copied to

Answer (score 4):

We can use the following function to move the entire folder which contains subfolders and files in it.

The destination path will have subfolders and files in it as in the source folder.

```
def move_folder_in_s3(bucket,source_folder,destination_path):
    s3_bucket = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3_bucket.Bucket(bucket)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=source_folder):
       print(object_summary.key)
       copy_source = {'Bucket': bucket,'Key': object_summary.key}
       destination = destination_path + object_summary.key.split(source_folder,1)[1]
       print(destination)
       s3.copy_object(CopySource=copy_source, Bucket=bucket, Key=destination)
```

And folder can be deleted from the source using the delete function.

```
def delete_folder_in_s3(bucket,folder):
    s3_bucket = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3_bucket.Bucket(bucket)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=folder):
        print(object_summary.key)
        s3.delete_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = object_summary.key)
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=(folder+'/'))
```